# unable to change the div class of html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the class name of a div whose id is "rvolatgeDiv". i want to change the class name of a div in a alarm function.

Code Snippet:

```js
function alarm() {
  //var value = document.getElementById("rvoltage").innerHTML;
  if ( rvoltage > 160 ||  rvoltage == 0 ) {
      document.getElementById('alarm').play();
      var img = document.getElementById('myImageId');
      img.style.visibility = 'visible';

      var div = document.getElementById('rvolatgeDiv');
      div.className="w3-col l3 w3-border  w3-red w3-xxlarge w3-text-black";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-row-padding">
   <div id="rvolatgeDiv" class="w3-col l3 w3-border  w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
      R-Voltage
      <br><br>
      <label id="ib1" class="w3-text-white"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 w3-border w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
       Y-Voltage
       <br><br>
       <label id="ib2" class="w3-text-white"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 w3-border w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
       B-Voltage
       <br><br>
       <label id="ib3" class="w3-text-white"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l3 w3-border w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
       Battery-Voltage
       <br><br>
       <label id="ib4" class="w3-text-white"></label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where is the `rvoltage` declared?

Comment: You code looks right. What was your error?

Comment: @Krishna Mohan did you want to change or remove the class for the defined div
according to your code it is removing the class name

Comment: yes @Wimanicesir. my code was right . don't know y it was not working ,  now its working. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
but you have to be sure that condition is true:
also your code here isn't full so I commented undefined elements.

- function alarm must be called as in your code isn't called.

```js
function alarm() {
        //var value = document.getElementById("rvoltage").innerHTML;
      // I declared rvoltage with value of 200 to make the condition true
        var rvoltage = 200;
        if ( rvoltage > 160 ||  rvoltage == 0 ) {
            //document.getElementById('alarm').play();
            var img = document.getElementById('myImageId');
            //img.style.visibility = 'visible';

            var div = document.getElementById('rvolatgeDiv');
            div.className="w3-col l3 w3-border  w3-red w3-xxlarge w3-text-black";
        }
    }
    // you can call the function here  or as on event like button click
    //alarm();
```

```css
.w3-red {
 color:red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="w3-row-padding">
            <div id="rvolatgeDiv" class="w3-col l3 w3-border  w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
                R-Voltage
                <br><br>
                <label id="ib1" class="w3-text-white"></label>

            </div>
            <div class="w3-col l3 w3-border w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
                Y-Voltage
                <br><br>
                <label id="ib2" class="w3-text-white"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col l3 w3-border w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
                B-Voltage
                <br><br>
                <label id="ib3" class="w3-text-white"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col l3 w3-border w3-gray w3-xxlarge w3-text-black" style="height:30%; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;">
                Battery-Voltage
                <br><br>
                <label id="ib4" class="w3-text-white"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- added button to check rvoltage -->
        <button onclick="alarm()">Check rvoltage</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have to remove the class `w3-gray` from the div you will need to change

```
div.className="w3-col l3 w3-border  w3-red w3-xxlarge w3-text-black";
```

to

```
div.classList.remove("w3-gray");
```

to add it again you can use this :

```
div.classList.add("w3-gray");
```

you can read about the `classList` more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: for adding it again, it should be `div.classList.add("w3-gray");`

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var divA=document.getElementById("divA");
    divA.classList.remove("bb");
    divA.classList.add("abc");
};

</script>
<div id="divA" class="aa bb">
    Testing
</div>
```

result

```
<div id="divA" class="aa abc">
Testing
</div>
```